# User profile property values are disappeared in SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile, user

We have configured a user profile multi-valued property ("Certificate") and it is used in our SharePoint 2010 environment since a year. Suddenly, the values of this property disappeared when I try with the user profile application to find the values for a user it does not show any thing. However, the management shell says it has two values but does not return any values(returns null).

what could the reason and how to fix?

Comment: Were these fields created in 2010, or were they part of a 2007 system that was upgraded?  Are you trying to synchronize this property?

Comment: No, it is created on sharepoint 2010 environment and it is not configured to sync.

Comment: Are your property values associated with Term Sets in your central admin? Check the Managed Metadata Service Application service in that case.

Comment: If it is Managed Metadata field and you're using Local Term Store, please review this: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/fromthefield/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=135.